# How to loop an array to output php XML file with simplexml

Tags: php, xml

Im trying to build a xml sitemap for the first time, so im stuck at the moment. I have the output but now I have to add the data to the xml file. I have provided the example on how far I am now, and im working on the part to loop all of the data which must be added to the xml output file.

**UPDATE: this is working now, any improvements are welcome!**

```
class XmlForSite{

    static function outputXml(){

        $xmlSitemap = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></urlset>');

        var smap = self::buildXml( $xmlSitemap );

        $xml        = $smap->asXml();
        $document   = new \DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
        $document->formatOutput = true;
        $document->loadXml($xmlSitemap->asXml());
        $xml = $document->saveXml();

        // final output, this will be used on a page somewhere
        return $xml;

    }

    public function buildXml(){

        // just an example, orginal array is bigger ;-)
        $files = array('lang'=>'url');

        foreach($files as $key => $value){

            // working but this must be in an array as output
            $url = $xmlSitemap->addChild('url');
            $url->addChild('loc', 'www' );
            $url->addChild('lastmod', 'mod' );
            $url->addChild('changefreq', 'daily');
            $url->addChild('priority', '1.0');

           //example on how i want to output it
           $output[] = '<url>
               <loc>' .$value. '</loc>
               <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="' .$key. '" href="' .$value. '"/>
           </url>';


        }

        return $xml;

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you go into detail about what the issue is? Btw, after your `$output[]` you have `';'` which would break the code

Comment: don't use string concatenation - use the proper methods for generating DOM nodes as it is far more reliable and basically intended for that purpose

Comment: You probably want to read up on the [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) API as you'll maybe find some of the methods such as [addAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addattribute.php) and [addChild](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) will help you greatly

Comment: I have seen the addAtrtribute & addChild element but where and how to add these?

Answer (score -1):

Taken directly from the PHP manual - should help with creating the nodes and adding the attributes. I can claim no credit for the code....

```
include 'example.php';

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$sxe->addAttribute('type', 'documentary');

$movie = $sxe->addChild('movie');
$movie->addChild('title', 'PHP2: More Parser Stories');
$movie->addChild('plot', 'This is all about the people who make it work.');

$characters = $movie->addChild('characters');
$character  = $characters->addChild('character');
$character->addChild('name', 'Mr. Parser');
$character->addChild('actor', 'John Doe');

$rating = $movie->addChild('rating', '5');
$rating->addAttribute('type', 'stars');

echo $sxe->asXML();
```